# Hibernate ORM modelling composite keys when to insert data into MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to insert data from a csv into a MySQL database maintain relationships between tables.

CSV format:

```
group1, John, 45, Hockey Fishing Movies
group1, Mary, 28, Dancing Fishing Rugby
group2, Ellen, 18, Fishing Netflix Facebook
group3, Paul, 19, Fishing Facebook Netflix
```

I have a database schema which looks like:

[image]

I have abstracted this example to fit my model and no problems with parsing, database connectivity etc. Purely with modelling this in hibernate and how to correctly perform insertion. Looked a few different hibernate tutorials but have not seen  what I am looking for. In terms of modelling this in hibernate, is hibernate the correct approach?

NOTE: only insertion is necessary

Thanks in advance, any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Which part of modelling this are you finding difficult? Are you referring to Person to Interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Person to Interest looks like many to many relation to me, with person_interest as the mapping table. You can model a bidirectional `@ManyToMany` relationship like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    .....

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "person_interest ", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "personId") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "interestId") }
    )
    private Set<Interest> interests = new HashSet();

    ..... other attributes and getter/setters
}
```

This is the reverse relation from interest to person.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Interest")
public class Interest{
    .....

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet();

    ..... other attributes and getter/setters
}
```

For further [reading](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany).